# how can I use a variable in a INDEX & MATCH statement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel 2010 and have a vba statement that works using hardcoded range limits, as below

```
Range(Range("F2"), Range("F" & lrow)).Value = "=INDEX('Acc plan'!$D$2:D300,MATCH(sageTB!$A$2:A300,'Acc plan'!$A$2:A300))"
```

I'd like to replace the value of 300 with a variable, but so far have failed miserably to get a version that doesn't just result in hash NAME in the results cell. Any tips would be very welcome

Comment: `"=INDEX('Acc plan'!$D$2:D" & foo & ",MATCH(sageTB!$A$2:A" & foo & ",'Acc plan'!$A$2:A" & foo & "))"` may be what you wanted, where foo is your variable number. I'd also suggest to [Fully qualify your references]( http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/11274/always-define-and-set-references-to-all-workbooks-and-sheets#t=201607261348479429911) instead of relying just on `Range("A1")` have it be `worksheetCodeName.Range("A1")`

Comment: Are you **sure** that is the .Formula (or .FormulaArray but not .Value) that you want? The 300 is going to grow as it is filled into the cells from F2 down and the multiple values in the Match's lookup parameter make it an array formula.

Comment: Make sure that you also try your formula manually. Even if you are able to replace it with a variable but your formula is invalid, you will still get #NAME error.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies, I appreciate the time taken. IvenBach your suggestion worked a treat.